# Why is docking permission denied?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have noticed that under certain conditions a station will deny my docking request.

What are the various conditions that can cause a station to deny a commander's docking request?

Comment: I am only aware of one: requesting docking permission from more than 7km away

Comment: Last night I was denied docking permission, but I was less than 5km from the station.

Comment: Permission will also be denied if there are no free landing pads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are more than 7.5 km away from the station when you request docking permission, or if the station has no free landing pads the station will deny your request. Stations will also deny your requests if you've annoyed the controlling faction sufficiently (i.e. you don't have enough reputation with them). As CmdrFreiheit pointed out in the comments, permission can also be denied if your ship is too large to land at the station.

Obviously in the first instance you just need to move closer to the station and try your request again. In the second instance, you could wait for a pad to free up, however if there are a bunch of AFK players there that could take a while. You could instead switch to solo mode and dock, do your stuff, then return to multiplayer. In the third instance you'll have to find some way of raising your reputation with the controlling faction before they will allow you to dock.

In the case of your ship being too large, you'll just have to find somewhere else to dock.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jon!  Last night I was playing in solo mode and I was denied docking permission (from about 2km away.)  Without increasing my reputation with the controlling faction, I was able to obtain permission to dock.  I didn't notice a lot of traffic at the time, and the station was a Ring style station with over 40 pads inside.

Comment: I think I may have been denied permission for speeding (as I was doing about 280 at the time, and I was pretty close to the station.)

Comment: I've never experienced being denied docking permission because I was travelling too quickly, but I also haven't played for a few months. It would be helpful if the stations told you why the request was denied really...

Comment: I believe you can also get docking permission denied if your ship is too large. Large ships can't dock at outposts.

Comment: @CmdrFreiheit Thanks - I will include that in the answer

Comment: So, the faction running this station gave me the mission to go to this station (from another system). I'm in range. I have a medium ship and the station has medium docks. I went into solo. Still I can't land at Forest Park in Sungai. Any ideas? Sure wish the station would TELL ME WHY! ... 10 minutes of trying ans as soon as I posted this it worked. Gotta be a bug. I was staring at an empty platform for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an ancient question, but it still pops on the first page on Google.

While everything JonK said is absolutely correct, there is a way to "fix" the problem. If too many ships are docked at a station (usually only a problem if you have to land at one of those small stations with only 3 pads), jump in and out of supercruise. This will usually free the pads, unless they are occupied by other players.

Answer (score 0):

This has been happening quite recently. Best way I found to fix it was to go back into supercruise and log out to menu and back in. Seems to fix the issue every time in solo at least.